# How to set think times between HTTP requests in bzm -Parallel Controller

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to set think times inside a "bzm-Parallel Controller" between HTTP-Requests, but unfortunately without success. 
In my attached test plan I tried to test the parallel controller with 3 requests, but all 3 requests will be started at the same time.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzLeX.png)
I want to set think times of 100-200 ms between each request.

Is there a possibility to configure the "bzm-Parallel Controller" in this way or is it only possible between "normal" requests without a parallel controller?

Answer (score 0):

`bzm-Parallel Controller` is something that is executing its children **in parallel**, to wit all 3 `MetadataX` requests will be started at exactly the same moment.

If you want a delay **between** these requests - move them outside of the `bzm-Parallel Controller`

More information on the concept:

- [Parallel Sampling for JMeter](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/parallel/Parallel.md)
- [How to Use the Parallel Controller in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-parallel-controller-in-jmeter/)